# Pulling out of a Cloud Storage bucket using C#

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

We are trying to figure out how to get something out of a Cloud Storage bucket using C# in GCP. We can see into the bucket, just not sure of the command to get it out of the bucket.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The Google maintained [GitHub repository](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dotnet-docs-samples/blob/master/storage/api/Storage/Storage.cs) generally has a bunch of examples in regards to using Cloud Storage client libraries with C#. You can always refer to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-usage-csharp) too.

In this particular case, if you wish to download an object from a Cloud Storage bucket you can use the following code snippet:

```
private void DownloadObject(string bucketName, string objectName,
    string localPath = null)
{
    var storage = StorageClient.Create();
    localPath = localPath ?? Path.GetFileName(objectName);
    using (var outputFile = File.OpenWrite(localPath))
    {
        storage.DownloadObject(bucketName, objectName, outputFile);
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"downloaded {objectName} to {localPath}.");
}
```

This will download an object named `objectName` from the bucket `bucketName` to the location specified by `localPath`. Replace these accordingly.